# Retrieve from database into JLabel

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

I want to retrieve data from database and display into JLabels .I am working in Netbeans and i have done this..

```
private void showActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     
  int row=jTable1.getSelectedRow();
  int column=jTable1.getSelectedColumn();
    String str=(String)jTable1.getValueAt(row,column); 

    try{
    rs=stat.executeQuery("select * from table3 where e_id='"+str+"'");

    jLabel1.setText(rs.getString("name"));
    jLabel12.setText(rs.getString("e_id"));

    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {System.out.print(e);}


}
```

Its unable to display anything.
I tried this in notepad and its working fine but not in netbeans.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: what exception u get/?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you should call [**ResultSet#next()**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html) before getting the column information.

```
 rs=stat.executeQuery("select * from table3 where e_id='"+str+"'");
    while(rs.next()){
    jLabel1.setText(rs.getString("name"));
    jLabel12.setText(rs.getString("e_id"));
    }
```

I strongly recommend you to use PreparedStatement instead of Simple Statement which would make your code prone to SQL Injection

Comment: Thankyou now its working. But why my code worked in notepad without rs.next()?

Comment: @ani you are welcome. I don't think it'd work w/o a call to ResultSet#next().

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
while (rs1.next()) {
    k= new Object[8][8]; 
    k[i][0] = rs1.getString("st_id");
    k[i][1] = rs1.getString("name");
    k[i][2] = rs1.getString("adm_year");
    k[i][3] = rs1.getString("crrt_year");
    k[i][4] = rs1.getString("mcode");
    k[i][5] = rs1.getString("grade");
    k[i][6] = rs1.getString("credit");
    k[i][7] = rs1.getString("attempt");
    System.out.println(k[i][4]);
    i++;

    }
    jTable1.setModel(new DefaultTableModel(k, new String[]{"Student ID", "Name", "Admmission Year", "Current Year", "Modules", "Grade", "Credit", "Attempt"}))
```